# Need help to import file.DAT into public/uploads folder using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to import file.DAT in the public/uploads folder.
However it didn't succeed. The error appear as a

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object.

Here's my code

Controller

```
<?php

class ImportController extends BaseController {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Import Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish to use controllers instead of, or in addition to, Closure
    | based routes. That's great! Here is an example controller method to
    | get you started. To route to this controller, just add the route:
    |
    |   Route::get('/', 'ImportController@index');
    |
    */

    public function showImport()
    {
        return View::make('import');
    }

    public function handleImport()
    {
        $file = Input::file('file'); // Your file upload input field in the form should be named 'file'

        $destinationPath = 'public/uploads/'.str_random(8);
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $uploadSuccess = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        if( $uploadSuccess ) {
            return Response::json('success', 200); // Or do a redirect with some message that file was uploaded
        } else {
            return Response::json('error', 400);
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<form action="{{ action('ImportController@handleImport') }}" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputFile">File Import</label>
        <input type="file" id="inputFile">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Import" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version, `Input::file('file');` can return different types.
Use `dd($file)` to see what $file is, based on that you can check if it is a file to proceed.